# Drill down into laravel eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem that’s broken into 2 parts:

## 1) I’m trying to get the specific events where rsvps = the logged in user_id.

## 2) And then filter that where event_date <= today to get the past events.

I’m getting stuck on #1. When I run

```
$favorites = Event::with('rsvps')->get();
```

I get all the events that include the rsvps which is good but I can’t filter it based on the rsvps info.

```
[
{"id":1,"user_id":"1","created_at":"2016-03-01 02:26:48","updated_at":"2016-03-01 02:26:48","event_name":"Awesome Event","event_venue":"The Rainbow Room","address":"612 Rachael Ln.","event_details":"Epic","event_date":"03\/12","image":"2016-03-01-02-26-48-heartHands.jpg","time":"8:00",
"rsvps":[
{"id":1,"created_at":"2016-03-01 02:28:39","updated_at":"2016-03-01 02:28:39","event_id":"1","user_id":"1"}]
},

{"id":2,"user_id":"1","created_at":"2016-03-01 02:40:05","updated_at":"2016-03-01 02:40:05","event_name":"New Event","event_venue":"My House","address":"612 Rachael Ln.","event_details":"Epic","event_date":"03\/01","image":"2016-03-01-02-40-05-img3.jpg","time":"8:00",
"rsvps":[
{"id":2,"created_at":"2016-03-01 02:40:12","updated_at":"2016-03-01 02:40:12","event_id":"2","user_id":"1"},

{"id":3,"created_at":"2016-03-01 22:21:33","updated_at":"2016-03-01 22:21:33","event_id":"2","user_id":"2"}
]}
]
```

When I run a test to just get the rsvps with the user_id = 1:

```
$favorites = Event::with('rsvps')->find('id')->where('rsvps->user_id', '1')->get();
```

it gives me the error: Call to a member function where() on null

Can someone please give me a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the relationship `rsvps`.  You are trying to query the `events`.

```
$favorites = Event::whereHas('rsvps', function($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', 1)
})->find('id');   // Passing in 'id' won't work here, it should be the actual id of an event.
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks so much

Comment: `with` is responsible for eager loading data and has nothing to do with actually querying the events with restrictions on the rsvps. You are looking for `has` instead

Comment: My revised code is picking up all of the events not just the one with the specific id:  

`$myFavs = Event::with(['rsvps' => function($q) {
        $q->where('user_id', 2);
      }])->get();`

Comment: I was able to get it working with this:

`$myFavs = Event::whereHas('rsvps', function($q) {
        $q->where('user_id', 2);
      })->get();`

Thanks guys!!